# How To Always Check For Inputs

Tags: java, input

Basically what I am asking is how do games check what the user inputs all the time, not just when the user is asked to input an integer or a word but I am ALL the time.

Example: Runescape, Minecraft, WoW, any game developed that uses text based communication always has that function that if you type in the pretty box it spits out what you said in a world chat box, how do I do that as such (Not a world chat box) but simply a put out.

Comment: Something like a `JTextBox`?

Comment: Please try to provide code you've attempted or be more specific with examples.

Comment: There's no one answer to this question. There are a million different ways to do this, and almost all of them depend on different frameworks -- GUI toolkits, game engines, and so on. You'll have to make this question _much_ more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, by `polling`. Games use loops which run 20+ times a second and check for whether the user is causing input via keyboard/mouse.

There are hundreds of great [tutorials](http://entropyinteractive.com/2011/02/game-engine-design-the-game-loop/)

Comment: Thank you, I actually didn't know how to really word it to search it up properly

Comment: Understood. The game loop also handles the game logic and rendering, that's how things are able to constantly move/updated.